# Rails 3.2.16 autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I have followed all things mentioned [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/1.0.13/frames). However, it is not working.  I have question_controller.  I am trying to come up with autocomplete search box.  I have created finders_controller.rb with the code route_to_app/app/controllers/finders_controller.rb

```
class FindersController < ApplicationController
autocomplete :question, :question
end
```

In the route I have following route_to_app/config/routes.rb

```
resources :finders do
  get :autocomplete_question_question, :on => :collection
end
```

In the view section route_to_app/app/views/questions/index.html.erb

```
 <div class = "span-24 last box">
    <%form_for @finder do |f|%>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :question_question,  autocomplete_question_question_finders_path %>
<%end%>
</div><!--End span-24 box.-->`
```

code route_to_app/app/views/finders/index.html.erb is blank.

Javascrip file looks like route_to_app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

I am getting following error message.  I am sure fundamentally wrong:

> undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
>   Showing C:/Sites/iHardie/app/views/questions/index.html.erb where line #8 raised:

```
        <div class = "span-24 last box">
    <%form_for @finder do |f|%>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :question_question, autocomplete_question_question_finders_path %>
<%end%>
</div><!--End span-24 box.-->
```

Can someone please help?  I am stuck here for some time.  I will buy a nice pizza or send a nice gift card to who will help me to solve the problem.

This is how question database looks like:

```
create_table "questions", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "question"
t.string   "answer"
t.integer  "product"
t.integer  "priority"
t.integer  "user"
t.string   "type"
t.boolean  "favorite"
t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false     end
```

Comment: I am trying to search in questions database by question.  Thanks.  Ideally i would like to place this in the menu bar.

Comment: Can you add a copy of what your Question model looks like?  You should be able to grab it from your schema.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Start out with the following, and we can take it from there if you are still having issues.

Now that you have posted the schema file there is one problem that jumps out right away.  You have declared the autocomplete as follows.

```
class FindersController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :question, :question
end
```

This should be used as follows

```
autocomplete :table_name, :method_name
```

This does not do auto pluralization so the table name needs to match what's in your database/schema.rb.  Here you have used `:table_name => :question`, but in your schema.rb file the table name is `questions`.

Trying changing this and let me know if you are having additional issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Nothing works.  Do you have any code that works.  I will copy and replicate that code.  thanks.